# Is it possible to set up CUDA 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 using apt-get nvidia driver?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to set up CUDA 8 on my Ubuntu 14.04.

However, I cannot normally install the nvidia driver using the `.run` file from nvidia website, because installing it causes the login loop and there seems to be no solution to that issue.

But if I install the driver using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367`, I'm able to log in to the system and there's no login loop. Though, the CUDA does not work if I do that, it says `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`.

The version of the `.run` driver is 367.57 and the version from `apt-get` is 367.57

I can't really see the difference between them however one of them causes the login loop *and* makes CUDA work properly, and the other one (`apt-get`) is not liked by CUDA at all.

---

Hence my question: is it possible to somehow set up CUDA to work with the driver I get using the `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 4):

From NVIDIA :

1. Perform the pre-installation actions.
2. Install repository meta-data

   Note: When using a proxy server with aptitude, ensure that `wget` is set up to use the same proxy settings before installing the cuda-repo package.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
   ```
3. Update the Apt repository cache

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install CUDA

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cuda
   ```

   Perform the post-installation actions.

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ixzz4ZDVWXs2z